# Ignore logging for some modules

Tags: python, logging

I have the following code:

```
from exhausted import main as main_exhausted

import logging

# Configure the log file
logging.basicConfig(
    filename="log/myprocess.log",
    level=logging.DEBUG
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_exhausted()
```

However, the log is including entries from the paramiko library, which is used in the exhausted module. What would be the way to allow logs created by the exhausted module but not paramiko?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to turn off Paramiko logging completely using for example

```
logging.getLogger('paramiko').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL + 1)
```

or use a different level such as `ERROR`, depending on if you want to allow e.g. `ERROR` and `CRITICAL` messages through from Paramiko.